# Python: How to get the string values of a 2D array greater than n characters long?

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = (["id" "title" "name"]
     ["1" "show" "anna"]
     ["2" "hide" "joh"]
)
```

I need to get the string values with more than 2 characters long.

Expected output:

```
s =  (["id" "title" "name"]
      [ ""   "show"  "anna"]
      [ ""   "hide"  "joh"]
)
```

I tried searching google but I didn't find a solution. Since the data is quite large I also tried `DataFrame.iterrows` or columns in `pandas` but it didn't get the desired result.

Can I use `pandas` to do this?

Comment: What is the format of your input data? What you've written out isn't valid Python syntax. Please edit your post so that it contains proper Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([["1", "show", "anna"],
                   ["2", "hide","joh"]], 
                  columns=["id", "title", "name"])
```

You can use `Series.apply` to check which string values of each column have a length greater than 2 (using `col.str.len() > 2`), and get a boolean mask.

Then use that mask with `DataFrame.where` to replace the values which don't satisfy that condition with empty strings `''`.

```
res = df.where(df.apply(lambda col: col.str.len() > 2), '')
```

Output:

```
>>> res

  id title  name
0     show  anna
1     hide   joh
```